# How to resolve "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a react-native application When trying to run yarn jest, I have this error:

[image]

react native version: "0.64.4"

Dependencies:

"react-native": "0.64.4",
"jest": "29.2.2"

The test file looks like this:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/App';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});`
```

I tried many solutions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of an error always occurs when using ES6 without babel being configured,

Can you try to run the tests with babel?

Also, in your jest configuration, do your have testEnvironment set to "node",
If yes, remove it.